# chart js different callback labels

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

Right now the callbacks (on hover) show the data from data set. I want to change each of that point with a different value. For that I have a same size array as the original data array.

I tried this

```
tooltips: {
     callbacks: {
       label: function(tooltipItem, data) {

       return measures;
       }
     }
},
```

but it returned the whole array for every point.

[image]

The chart can have more then 1 datasets. They are created dynamically in a for loop. I tried creating the callbacks dynamically as well

```
call[r] = {
   abel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
   return measures;
   }
};

tooltips: {
     callbacks: call
},
```

But that just threw TypeErrors

> TypeError: c.callbacks.labelColor is undefined
>
> TypeError: e.title is undefined

How can i get each array element on a different point? And in case of multiple datasets show the values from the same position array as dataset?

Sorry if im not clear enough. Just cant quite wrap my head around this.

Thanks!

Comment: You get the point value out of the [`tooltipItem`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-item-interface) object passed to the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented graph in one of my project for Power On Time duration. I have refered you with my code. Please see if it can help.

Labels Array:

Array(9)
0
:
"2018-09-17"
1
:
"2018-09-17"
2
:
"2018-09-17"
3
:
"2018-09-17"
4
:
"2018-09-17"
5
:
"2018-09-17"
6
:
"2018-09-17"
7
:
"2018-09-17"
8
:
"2018-09-18"

Data Array:

Array(9)
0
:
"200"
1
:
"211"
2
:
"234"
3
:
"255"
4
:
"300"
5
:
"321"
6
:
"400"
7
:
"421"
8
:
"00421"

```
<script>
 var powerontimedata_chart_labels=[];
 var powerontimedata_chart_data=[];

function initiateChart(labels, data){
    chart_labels=JSON.parse(labels);
    chart_data=JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(powerontimedata_chart_labels);
    console.log(powerontimedata_chart_data);
    plotDataLineChart();
 }

function plotDataLineChart(){
  var lineChartOptions = {
 maintainAspectRatio: false,
steppedLine         : 'after',
responsive : true,
showTooltips : false,
showInlineValues : true,
centeredInllineValues : true,
tooltipCaretSize : 0,
tooltipTemplate : "<%= value %>",
scales: {
  xAxes: [{

                position: "right",
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    stepSize : 1,
                    autoSkip: false,
                    labelString: "Date",
                    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                    fontColor: "black",
                },

    ticks:{
      stepSize : 2,
      autoSkip: true
    }
  }],
  yAxes: [{

    position: "left",
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    stepSize : 1,
                    autoSkip: false,
                    labelString: "Time in Hour",
                    fontFamily: "Montserrat",
                    fontColor: "black",
                },
    ticks: {

      beginAtZero:true,

      autoSkip: true
    }
  }]
},
"animation": {
  "duration": 1,
  "onComplete": function() {
    var chartInstance = this.chart,
    ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
    console.log(ctx);
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
    ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';

    this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
      var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
      meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
        var data = dataset.data[index];
        ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
      });
    });
  }
},
        //multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"

    };

    var lineChartCanvas          = $('#weekbarChart').get(0).getContext('2d')


    var ontime = {
      labels : chart_labels,
      datasets : [
      {
        label : 'Power Ontime',
        fill                :  true,
        borderColor : "#FF0000",
        backgroundColor : "#F5B7B1",

        data : powerontimedata_chart_data,
        steppedLine: false,
        pointStyle: 'clearInterval',
        pointBorderColor : "#FF0000",


    }
    ]
}
realTimeChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: ontime,
  options: lineChartOptions
});


}
initiateChart('<?= json_encode($chart["labels"])?>','<?= json_encode($chart["data"])?>');
</script>
```

And my graph comes out to be :

[image]